# Hide/Show Text Field Based upon Radio Button

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have 3 radio buttons in my visaulforce page, and 2 text fields. When I click the first radio button, at that time the first text field should be displayed. When I click the second radio button, the second field should be displayed. When I click the third radio button, again, the second field should be displayed. I am using javascript to hide/show the text fields but it's not working. Can anyone please give me a suggestion?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function show(t)
{
    if ( t.value == 0 ){
        document.getElementById("defaultcost").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("differcost").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("defaultcost").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("differcost").style.display = 'block';
    }     
}
</script>
```

VF Page

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:selectRadio value="{!Quote__c.shipping_type__c}" onChange="show(this);">
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Use Store Settings" itemValue="0" />
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Per Item" itemValue="1" />
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Fixed Price Per Order" itemValue="2" />   
    </apex:selectRadio>

    <apex:inputField value="{!Quote__c.storeprice__c}" id="defaultcost" style="display:block;"/><br/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Quote__c.price__c}" id="differcost" style="display:none;"/><br/>         
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you have there 2 errors in javascript:

1. You can't access a `select.value` element directly in javascript (only by using jquery or other framework). So you should change the `t.value` and get selected value using other code. [google knows](https://www.google.es/search?q=stack%20overflow%20javascript%20get%20selected%20value&oq=stack%20overflow%20javascript%20get%20selected%20value&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.16246j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)
2. You can't reference directly in javascript using `getElementById` a field input id that has been set in visualfore (*defaultcost*), that is because SF create the input html element adding a "special" id. for instance: `id_j7.ju77_3.defaultcost`

My suggestion is to include **jquery** in your page an replace your javascript show method by this:

```
function show(t)
{
    if ( $(t).val() == 0 ){

        $('[id$="defaultcost"]').show();
        $('[id$="differcost"]').hide();
    }
    else{
       $('[id$="defaultcost"]').hide();
       $('[id$="differcost"]').show();

    }     
}
```

Comment: I used your code but it is not working may i know what is the problem

Comment: I used your code but when i click on 2nd radio button at that time 2field will not displaying.what is the problem.

Comment: Have you added the jQuery? What error you see?

Comment: Now it's get saved but when i click 2nd radion button at that time 2 field is not displaying.

Comment: The sample code had a typo. Pls, check it again.